# Ubuntu configure keyboard non-interactive

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, automation, keyboard

Im setting up some Chef scripts to build and configure a Ubuntu 11.04 instance for development.

I'm having some trouble finding away of reconfiguring the keyboard with no user interaction.

I tried using `setxkbmap gb` but this resets as soon as you reboot the vm and not all programs seem to honour this setting.

Can someone please point me to the correct file or command to change the keyboard layout and persist it over sessions and programs.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to edit the files but it doesn't help, but simply executing  the command below helped:

```
sudo loadkeys gb
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `/etc/default/console-setup`

This should be loaded from the `console-setup` scripts in your initrd. See `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/console_setup` for an idea of what they do.